# Flutter google map how to instanciate a GoogleMapController outside of the GoogleMap's widget onCreated function for testings?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, testing

I'm using plugin google_maps_flutter 1.2.0, and i want to instanciate a GoogleMapController for testing some bloc's event, where the controller's value can't be null.
Unfortunalty, i don't know how to do it, because to my knows, GoogleMapController  can't be instanciate outside of the function 'OnCreated' of the GoogleMap() Widget.

```
 GoogleMap(onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                         // Can only be instanciate here
                        },
          );
```

It's impossible to do something like this :

```
  GoogleMapController controller = new GoogleMapsController();
```

I can only do this, and controller is null :

```
 GoogleMapController controller;
```

I tried multiple thing but nothing is working, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

First, `GoogleMapController _googleMapController` in your `_WidgetState`.
Then

```dart
GoogleMap(onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _googleMapController = controller;
    }
);
```

After Google Map Created, you can use _googleMapController everywhere in your widget.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i already know this (thats write in my post). My question is : is there another way to do it ? Because i need to insanciate a GoogleMapController in a test file, and i don’t know how to do it without load a map ?

Comment: `GoogleMapController` is use to control the map. I don't know why you need a controller without a map.   Without the map, controller is useless.

Comment: Need it for testing a bloc, because i gave it in argument the map controller.

Comment: how to mock the google maps controller to do unit tests on it?

Comment: You can try to make a `GoogleMap()` out of the widget tree and get `controller` from `onMapCreated`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this - In your state:

```
final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();
```

and in you GoogleMap() widget as this

```
 GoogleMap(
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) =>
              _googleMapController.complete(controller),
          initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `_googleMapController? = controller;` before the build method the make a little if statement `(_googleMapController != null)` where you want to use your method or what ever you want to do with the instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Flutter 2.5.3 and later you can add a late in front of the variable declaration i.e `late GoogleMapController _googleMapController;`

In your googlemap widget you can use the variable as normal `onMapCreated: (controller) => _googleMapController = controller,`